# Android Calculator Truncating unnecessary decimal place after the result

Tags: android, calculator, decimal-point

I am getting results always in decimal format like if I enter '1', it gets converted into '1.0' and final result also comes in decimal format. Can anyone tell me how to display user inputs always in simple format instead of decimal format?

This is related to my previous post :

```
private void handleEquals(int newOperator) {
if (hasChanged) {
switch (operator) {
case 1:
    num = num + Double.parseDouble(txtCalc.getText().toString());
    break;
case 2:
    num = num - Double.parseDouble(txtCalc.getText().toString());
    break;
case 3:
    num = num * Double.parseDouble(txtCalc.getText().toString());
    String strNum = null; 
    strNum = Double.toString(num);
    if(strNum.contains("E")){
    strNum = strNum.substring(0, 6) + strNum.substring(strNum.indexOf("E"));
    }
    Log.i("MULTIPLICATION","Checking Precision");
    System.out.println("New StrNum is: " + strNum);
    num = Double.valueOf(strNum);
    break;
case 4:
    num = num / Double.parseDouble(txtCalc.getText().toString());
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line before `break` in every case.

```
int number = (int)num;
```

Updated answer:

```
int num;
num = num + (int)Double.parseDouble(txtCalc.getText().toString());
```

or

```
int num;
num = num + Integer.parseInt(txtCalc.getText().toString());
```

Comment: Doing so will give an error that duplicate variable! Isn't so?

Comment: num and number is two different variable.so why duplicate variable?Anyway,i updated my answer.

Comment: I think @YuAndroid wants answers to be left in decimal format if they are not integers.

Answer (score 0):

You should test if your number is an integer:

```
String result;

if (num==(int)num) {
    result = String.valueOf((int)num);
} else {
    result = String.valueOf(num);
}

// display result to user
```

Comment: This code should go after your switch statement, I would guess, after you have modified your number.

Comment: But mine variable 'num' is of type 'Double'

Comment: Replace `(int)` with `long`? The result string would look like `"5"` and not `"5.0..."` or whatever extended number if you cast to any non-decimal type. I'm not quite sure I understand you.

Comment: I meant to say replace `(int)` with `(long)`. Maybe your calculator requires the use of the [`BigInteger`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) class.